# Change order of dates in R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I have been working on a plot in R using ggplot and plotting dates on the x axis. I have noticed that R does not recognize them as dates, and so the order on the x axis is wrong. I have tried many different things such as using as.Date(), manually editing levels and ordering the x axis, but nothing has worked. Here's my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

calories_data = read.csv('dailyCalories_clean.csv',header = TRUE, sep=",")

ggplot(calories_data, aes(x= ActivityDay, y=Calories, group=Id, color = Id))+
  geom_line()
```

[Here's the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgTnn.jpg)

I appreciate any help, I'm new at this and have been researching for hours with no success. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. If you want to post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 10))` for the first ten rows of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to fix your issue would be to convert your dates to proper dates to fix the order and use the `date_labels` argument of `scale_x_date` to format your dates. To convert to dates you have to add a fake year to your `ActivityDay`, e.g. `"2022"`:

Using some fake random data to mimic your real data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

calories_data <- data.frame(
  ActivityDay <- rep(c("4/1", "4/10", "5/11", "5/1"), 3),
  Id = rep(1:3, each = 4),
  Calories = runif(12, 1000, 3000)
)

calories_data$ActivityDay <- as.Date(paste("2022", calories_data$ActivityDay, sep = "/"), format = "%Y/%m/%d")

ggplot(calories_data, aes(x= ActivityDay, y=Calories, group=Id, color = Id))+
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "5 day", date_labels = "%m/%d")
```

[image]